# Why does two same strings doesnt equals?

Tags: android, string, equals, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have a following code:

```
int nb=0;
wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
wifi.startScan();
result=wifi.getScanResults();
int sizeList=vysledek.size();

if(result==null) {

    Log.d( LOG,"ERROR");

} else {

    for(int i=0; i<sizeList; i++) {

        Log.d("Check",result.get(i).SSID);
        if (result.get(i).SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(ssid)) {
            Log.d("SSID",ssid);
             nb++;
        }
        //Log.d("nb:",Integer.toString(nb)+"Size:"+Integer.toString(sizeList));

    }
}
```

I´m connected to the wifi network called ABC and `result.get(0).SSID`, `result.get(1).SSID` and `result.get(2).SSID` are also ABC. Why does that if statement doesn't increase nb? nb is still 0 in all cases.
Thanks all

Comment: @donfuxx Or `equalsIgnoreCase()`, as shown in the above code...

Comment: exactly, I´m using equalsIgnoreCase() or equals() both failed

Comment: not possible,might be u are having some additional spaces which u have missed to be cared.

Comment: Are you **sure** `ssid` contains `"ABC"`? Take a look at all of the values, whether in a debugger or by logging, to make sure they're *exactly* the same (ignoring case).

Comment: I´m using the exact code I´ve posted, no additional spaces there or anything. It just doesnt work :(

Comment: please add sysout for those values before compare and post log for similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getScanResults() will give SSID with double quote e.g. your ABC will be "ABC" when accessed through result.get(i).SSID.

So remove those quotes before you compare.

```
/**
 * remove double quote from start and end of the string
 */
private String unornamatedSsid(String ssid) {
    ssid = ssid.replaceFirst("^\"", "");
    return ssid.replaceFirst("\"$", "");
}
```

Use above function:

```
String scannedSSid = unornamatedSsid(result.get(i).SSID);
if (scannedSSid.equalsIgnoreCase(ssid)) {
}
```